# Elastic Query with `aggs` inside `must`

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

Is there any way where we can `aggs` inside the inside the `must` .??
I have a query which hold multiple conditions and one aggregation, and aggregation must be part of `AND` clause (i mean `must`)

query look something like this ...

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "actualIndex",
            "min_children": 1,
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "actualIndex.datetime": {
                  "gte": "now-364d/d",
                  "lt": "now/d"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "has_child": {
                  "type": "actualIndex",
                  "min_children": 3,
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "actualIndex.array1.cloumA": "abc"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "actualIndex.array1.cloumB": "xyz"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "has_child": {
                  "type": "actualIndex",
                  "min_children": 2,
                  "query": {
                    "terms": {
                      "actualIndex.array1.mno": [
                        "value1",
                        "value2",
                        "value3"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "query": {
                  "range": {
                    "actualIndex.datetime": {
                      "gte": "now-364d/d",
                      "lt": "now/d"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "groupby": {
                    "composite": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "ids": {
                            "terms": {
                              "field": "ids"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                      "total": {
                        "children": {
                          "type": "actualIndex"
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                          "range_bucket": {
                            "date_range": {
                              "field": "actualIndex.datetime",
                              "keyed": true,
                              "ranges": {
                                "from": "now-364d/d",
                                "to": "now",
                                "key": "bucket"
                              }
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                              "BAS_TOTAL": {
                                "sum": {
                                  "field": "actualIndex.amountField"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "sum_intermediate": {
                            "max_bucket": {
                              "buckets_path": "range_bucket>BAS_TOTAL"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "inventory_selector": {
                        "bucket_selector": {
                          "buckets_path": {
                            "total": "total > sum_intermediate"
                          },
                          "script": "params.total > 1000"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I just need the result of `aggs` should be the part of `must` too

can anybody look help here.

P.S Score is not important.

Answer (score 0):

we can use multiple `aggs` and this problem can solve via script.

```
{
  "inventory_selector": {
    "bucket_selector": {
      "buckets_path": {
        "total": "total > sum_intermediate",
        "actualPrice" : "price>sum_intermediate"
      },
      "script": "params.total > 1000 && params.actualPrice <= 500"
    }
  }
}
```

`&&` can be use for `must` operation and `||` can be use for should operation.